# SQL query valid in phpMyAdmin, but invalid in node.js using mysql package

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to write a script that automatically downloads some items from a database in node.js, but am running into an error using the `mysql` package (latest version: 2.15). I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT `R1`, `R2`, `Flags` FROM `table`  WHERE `Flags` = 'F1' OR `Flags` = 'F2'
```

This works just fine if I manually run this query through phpMyAdmin, but when I create and run the exact same query using node.js, I get the error `Error: ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I've also tried using `IN ('F1', 'F2')`, but that doesn't work either. However, if I take out the items after the `OR` (so it just filters on one value), it works through node.js.

Is there something wrong with my query that's throwing these errors? Or is there another way to filter on multiple values that works for the mysql package?

Comment: Maybe the ticks in the select clause. Just remove them and see if it works. Like so:
`SELECT R1, R2, Flags FROM table WHERE Flags = 'F1' OR Flags = 'F2'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately removing the ticks didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know if you already solved this or not, but it may be helpful to see how you are passing the query on the node.js app. Maybe start with a simple query like `SELECT 1` and see if that returns an error. Maybe is not the query itself ¯\_(ツ)_/¯